# Find users that have a role attached to an instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rolify

I am working on a website with 3 types of users and a "case" that will have a User of each type.
Instead of defining Facilitator, Customer and Diagnostician Models, I went for defining them as Roles, using Rolify. Still not sure that's the best solution though.

Anyway, I have 2 models :
User
Case

```
class Case < ApplicationRecord
    resourcify
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  rolify strict: true
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  belongs_to :role

  after_create :assign_default_role
  def assign_default_role
    self.add_role "newuser" if self.roles.blank?
  end

end
```

3 roles :
Facilitator
Customer
Diagnostician

For each case, I will define one and only one role.

To experiment, I have created a user and a case and gave the role "facilitator" to this user for this case.

**I am trying to retrieve the user with the role "facilitator" from the case** but I am unable to do it using :

```
Case.first.roles.where(name: "facilitator").first

Case.first.find_roles(:facilitator)
```

I couldn't find a solution reading Rolify Wiki.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
user= User.with_role(:facilitator).first
```

I assume you have a join table for the roles perhaps called :users_roles

Comment: I am looking for users that have the facilitator for the instance Case.first